# SharePoint Designer has stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm having an issue with SharePoint Designer....this is for SharePoint online

From "Send Email" action>To> when I click on "people/groups from SharePoint Site.....SharePoint Designer crashes ....I get a message "SP Designer has stopped working "

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out the issue....I found a few blogs with similar issues and they are talking  about the IIS being set up for two web site binding.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of your SPD ?

As I know this is a bug and fixed in 4402 version , please upgrade SPD at least 4402 .